# RatingBar with small white stars

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

The following is the xml for my rating bar.

```
<RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:stepSize="0.5"
                android:rating="4.5"/>
```

I am happy with its size but I would like to stars to be white on grey (white for filled and grey for empty).

I am looking at this tutorial (http://www.materialdoc.com/rating-bar/) but I am not sure how to adapt the style to suit the small appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use progressTint for this purpose

```
  <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/vendorRatingBarValue"
                        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reviewerName"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:isIndicator="true"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:progressTint="@color/white"

                        android:transformPivotX="0dp"

                        />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is correct and easy to implement.

Answer (score 4):

You can try drawable

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

     <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

     <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_on" />

    </layer-list>

<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_selector"
        android:isIndicator="true"
                android:stepSize="0.5"
                android:rating="4.5" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you would need to use the attributes

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"

android:progressTint="@color/white"
```

so..

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rb_doctor"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressTint="@color/white"
    android:rating="0"
    android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/white"
    android:stepSize="1.0" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example of [RatingBar](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/).

Custom white and gray star can possible with custom theme for this and specify small size so size of rating bar star will be same as default small size theme.

You have to create drawable for custom rating bar and make sure about the size of rating bar because here height of rating bar matters a lot.i mean if your star image is size of 13dp height and rating bar is 17dp height than it will stretch the rating bar so make sure about height.

Here is simple example of how can create custom selector for rating bar.

Star Drawable

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_empty_small" /> 
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_empty_small" /> 
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_empty_small" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_empty_small" /> 
  </selector>
```

Style for rating bar

```
<style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
  <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/inf_full_ratingbar</item> 
  <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item> 
  <item name="android:width">20dip</item> 
  <item name="android:height">20dip</item> 
  <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item> 
  </style>
```

And than use custom style for rating bar like:

```
     <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBarFlight"
            style="@style/StarRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/rating_bar_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/library_screen" />
```